# Angular2 CLI ng build places all files in one folder

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-cli

I am just exploring angular cli. I tried to build my project by following command:

```
ng build
```

It creates a folder dist and places all bundles and index file in it.

I know that we can specify the outdir in angular-cli.json and cli will generate all bundles and index.html file in the specified folder.

What I need is, I want the bundled js files to be placed in:

```
/dist/js/ folder
```

and index file in

```
/dist/ folder
```

I tried, copying the generated js bundles to the dist/js folder and updated the paths in index file but it didnt work and console shows 404 for bundles.

One more question, the ng build command generates .gzip files as well. What is its purpose and how do I use it in my app?

Answer (score -1):

There is no possible way for that.

> One of the largest reasons I can see for keeping the Webpack config hidden is keeping the option open to migrate off of Webpack or takes on some of the functionality in the future. Exposing the internal build tool dependency to end users is a proven path to endless difficulties.

See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-239498563)

**Edit:**

You can achive this by using gulp.

after **ng build** use this **gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  mkdirp = require('mkdirp'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', [], function () {
  mkdirp('./dist/images', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  mkdirp('./dist/fonts', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{woff,woff2,eot,ttf}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{woff,woff2,eot,ttf}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  mkdirp('./dist/js', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{bundle.js,bundle.map,js.gz}')
        .pipe(replace(/"([a-z0-9]+)\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)"/g, '"..\/fonts\/$1\.$2"'))
        .pipe(replace(/"([a-z0-9]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)"/g, '"..\/images\/$1\.$2"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{bundle.js,bundle.map,js.gz}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  gulp.src('./dist/index.html')
    .pipe(replace(/src="([a-z0-9]+)\.bundle\.js"/g, 'src="js\/$1\.bundle\.js"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/.'));

});
```

and after **ng build -prod** use this **gulpfile.prod.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  mkdirp = require('mkdirp'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', [], function () {
  mkdirp('./dist/images', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  mkdirp('./dist/fonts', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{woff,woff2,eot,ttf}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{woff,woff2,eot,ttf}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  mkdirp('./dist/js', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{bundle.js,bundle.map,js.gz}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.{bundle.js,bundle.map,js.gz}')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  mkdirp('./dist/css', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    } else {
      gulp.src('./dist/**.css')
        .pipe(replace(/url\(([a-z0-9]+)\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)(\?#[a-z0-9_-]+)?\)/g, 'url(..\/fonts\/$1\.$2$3)'))
        .pipe(replace(/url\(([a-z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|png|svg)(#[a-z0-9_-]+)?\)/g, 'url(..\/images\/$1\.$2$3)'))
        .pipe(replace(/sourceMappingURL=(\w+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.bundle\.map/g, 'sourceMappingURL=../js\/$1\.$2\.bundle\.map'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/.'));
      gulp.src('./dist/**.css')
        .pipe(clean());
    }
  });

  gulp.src('./dist/index.html')
    .pipe(replace(/href="(\w+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.bundle\.css"/g, 'href="css\/$1\.$2\.bundle\.css"'))
    .pipe(replace(/src="(\w+)\.([a-z0-9]+)\.bundle\.js"/g, 'src="js\/$1\.$2\.bundle\.js"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/.'));
});
```

You can also add npm script to package.json file for this job.

```
scripts: {
    .
    .
    "build": "ng build && gulp",
    "bprod": "ng build -prod && gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.prod.js"
}
```